# My JavaScript split function not working

Tags: javascript, google-maps, split

I have the following code which through Google Maps API gets the latitude and longitude of the position clicked on the map

```
var latitude_longitude = evt.latLng;
```

When I alert the variable using the code below the following is displayed:
(53.4128,-1.51165)

```
   alert(latitude_longitude);////Gets latitude and Longitude - Latitude first - Longitude second
```

However I now need to split  (53.4128,-1.51165) into 2 variables Latitude and Longitude and have tried using the code below:

```
var myarr = latitude_longitude.split(",");
var latitude = myarr[0];
alert(latitude);
```

However the alert doesn't show and I am unsure why?

Comment: Are you getting any errors on your console? Developers Tools (F12 for IE, Chrome) -> console tab

Comment: Are you sure that `latitude_longitude` isn't an array already?

Comment: in the alert, you are seeing the 'toString()' representation of the latLng object. for example, window.toString() will give you "[object Window]",   same as alert(window)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try:

```
var latitude = evt.latLng.lat();
```

Answer (score 0):

Given this:

```
var latlng = '53.4128,-1.51165';
console.log(latlng);
var lat = latlng.split(",")[0];
console.log(lat);
```

I get the output:

```
53.4128,-1.51165
53.4128
```

So splitting on the comma is perfectly valid for a string variable with a comma in it. However, I suspect that your `latitude_longitude` is not a string. Open Developer Tools (or its equivalent for the browser you are using), set a breakpoint and examine the variable. I suspect you will see that it is an object with properties and that you can just access those properties instead of trying to parse its string representation.

Answer (score 0):

first check if your variable is an object or string:

```
 alert(typeof latitude_longitude);
```

if your alert output is "object" so you need to convert it to string

```
var strLatLong=String(latitude_longitude);
var LangLat = strLatLong.split(",");
alert(typeof strLatLong);
```

....it worked for me